# r order of dataframe and selection

Tags: r, selection

I would appreciate if someone could give me some direction of how to solve a complex ordering of a matrix and selection of the top 2 elements in each subcategory.

code:

```
index<-1:14
metric<-c(0.037777,0.041143,0.041043,0.042056,0.043701,0.042169,0.042134,
          0.046565,0.044638,0.036653,0.046221,0.04033,0.045385,0.043873)
cat_1<-c("California Munis","California Munis","California Munis","California Munis",
         "California Munis","California Munis","California Munis","Corporate Bonds",
         "Corporate Bonds","Corporate Bonds","Government Bonds","Government Bonds",
         "High Yield Bonds","High Yield Bonds")
cat_2<-c("California Munis","Corporate Bonds","Corporate Bonds","Government Bonds",
         "High Yield Bonds","High Yield Bonds","High Yield Bonds","High Yield Bonds",
         "High Yield Bonds","High Yield Bonds","California Munis","California Munis",
         "Corporate Bonds","Corporate Bonds")

data<-data.frame(cbind(index,metric,cat_1,cat_2))
```

which produces the below matrix

```
Ind Metric     Cat_1                Cat_2
1   0.037777    California Munis    California Munis
2   0.041143    California Munis    Corporate Bonds
3   0.041043    California Munis    Corporate Bonds
4   0.042056    California Munis    Government Bonds
5   0.043701    California Munis    High Yield Bonds
6   0.042169    California Munis    High Yield Bonds
7   0.042134    California Munis    High Yield Bonds
8   0.046565    Corporate Bonds     High Yield Bonds
9   0.044638    Corporate Bonds     High Yield Bonds
10  0.036653    Corporate Bonds     High Yield Bonds
11  0.046221    Government Bonds    California Munis
12  0.04033     Government Bonds    California Munis
13  0.045385    High Yield Bonds    Corporate Bonds
14  0.043873    High Yield Bonds    Corporate Bonds
```

Given the matrix above I would like to order based on the Cat_1, Cat_2 and Metric. i have tried this:

```
data[order(data[,3],data[,4],data[,2]),]
```

However Cat_1 and Cat_2 should be indifferent if their entries are the same. As an example, "California Munis"&"Corporate Bonds"="Corporate Bonds"&"California Munis". the outcome I am looking to get should look like the result in the following matrix

```
Ind Metric      Cat_1               Cat_2               Selection
1   0.037777    California Munis    California Munis    1
2   0.041143    California Munis    Corporate Bonds     1
3   0.041043    California Munis    Corporate Bonds     2
11  0.046221    Government Bonds    California Munis    1
4   0.042056    California Munis    Government Bonds    2
12  0.04033     Government Bonds    California Munis    
5   0.043701    California Munis    High Yield Bonds    1
6   0.042169    California Munis    High Yield Bonds    2
7   0.042134    California Munis    High Yield Bonds    
8   0.046565    Corporate Bonds     High Yield Bonds    1
13  0.045385    High Yield Bonds    Corporate Bonds     2
9   0.044638    Corporate Bonds     High Yield Bonds    
14  0.043873    High Yield Bonds    Corporate Bonds 
10  0.036653    Corporate Bonds     High Yield Bonds
```

The last column presents the selection of the top 2 lines per every subcategory that I need to extract.

Any ideas or code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear how you expect the ordering to be as shown.  eg, how did index 11 make it up to the 4th row?

Comment: because c("Government Bonds","California Munis")=c("California Munis","Government Bonds") so the same grouping as 11, 4, and 12, and had the highest metric compared to 4 and 12. Does this make sense?

Comment: I would start  by defining the categories in a way that takes care of commutation, e.g. paste cat_1 and cat_2 together with sep=" ", then strsplit on " ", and sort that character vector, and then paste it back together into a string... these are your categories. Now it is fairly easy to pick top two items in yield for each category.

Answer (score 2):

Please abandon the use of `data.frame(cbind(...))`. It will only cause you grief.

```
 newdat <- data[ with( data, 
                order( pmax( as.numeric(cat_1), as.numeric(cat_2) ), 
                       pmin( as.numeric(cat_1), as.numeric(cat_2) ) ,
                     - metric) ) , ]
 newdat$selection <- ave(index, 
                         first=pmax( as.numeric(newdat$cat_1), 
                                     as.numeric(newdat$cat_2) ), 
                        second= pmin( as.numeric(newdat$cat_1), 
                                      as.numeric(newdat$cat_2) ) ,
                         FUN=seq)
#-----------------------------------------
> newdat
   index   metric            cat_1            cat_2 selection
1      1 0.037777 California Munis California Munis         1
2      2 0.041143 California Munis  Corporate Bonds         1
3      3 0.041043 California Munis  Corporate Bonds         2
11    11 0.046221 Government Bonds California Munis         1
4      4 0.042056 California Munis Government Bonds         2
12    12 0.040330 Government Bonds California Munis         3
5      5 0.043701 California Munis High Yield Bonds         1
6      6 0.042169 California Munis High Yield Bonds         2
7      7 0.042134 California Munis High Yield Bonds         3
8      8 0.046565  Corporate Bonds High Yield Bonds         1
13    13 0.045385 High Yield Bonds  Corporate Bonds         2
9      9 0.044638  Corporate Bonds High Yield Bonds         3
14    14 0.043873 High Yield Bonds  Corporate Bonds         4
10    10 0.036653  Corporate Bonds High Yield Bonds         5
```

The requirement for success here is that the levels in the two cat variables are the same. If not, then make them the same with `levels(.) <- union(levels(cat1, levels(cat_2))`

Comment: thanks a lot @DWin. the first part worked very nicely with my data however I cannot make it work with the way you constructed the selection. i suspected is the index cause it is not sequential in my full dataset. what does index do within the ave function? thank you again

Comment: Have you made sure that the levels of the two columns are constructed identically? The code I offered to fix that potential problem was not complete.

Answer (score 1):

I expand on my comment

```
# introduce combined category
cat3 <- sapply(paste(data$cat_1,data$cat_2,sep=" "),function(x){paste(sort(strsplit(x," ")[[1]]), collapse=" ")})
data$cat_3 <- cat3
# order as desired
data1 <- data[order( cat_3 , -metric), ]
# label and select top 2 in each cat
data1$rankByCat <- unlist(sapply(unique(data1$cat_3), function(mycat, mydf)  {return(1:sum(mydf$cat_3==mycat))}, mydf=data1))
data1[data1$rankByCat < 3, !names(data1)%in%c("cat_3")]
```

Answer (score 0):

@andrei

I have got the sorting part with the following code:

```
#concacenate the 2 strings
cat_3<-paste(data[,3],data[,4],sep="  ")

#break the string to 2 (creates a list)
temp_split<-strsplit(cat_3,"  ")

#sort by row
sort_split<-sapply(temp_split,sort)

#bind split
out<-cbind(data,t(sort_split))
```

Is that the best way to write it?

How would I proceed from here to select the top 2 of each category?

Thanks for the help!